# login loop after ubuntu 20.04 update

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics, login

the Ubuntu 20.04 automatic updater (software updater) asked me to allow to install updates.
I agreed to update, but at 70% an error appeared.
I didn't pay attention to it, but after I put the PC to sleep and then turned it back, I ended up being asked for my password, entering it, but it comes back to ask for my password indefinitely.

I have read online and dealt with the permissions of files, but it seems it's not due to those.
I believe it's due to the Nvidia Graphics Drivers.

The recommended driver for my PC seems to be nvidia-340
My video card is GeForce GT220.
I cannot install nvidia-340 in the usual way using sudo apt-get install : I get "errors were encountered while processing: nvidia-340". I believe this is due to the linux kernel I have.

What could I possibly do? Please help me!

I can log-in via xfce4-session (at login time, I press the ubuntu logo and press the 3rd option : xfce4-session).

EDIT: I can get an nVidia-340 .run file by using the tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m972Op8BWU&t=187s&ab_channel=if-not-true-then-false.com
I can run it and I successfully installed it.
When writing `sudo apt-cache policy nvidia-340`, I do get the `Installed` word appearing in the output.

But still, I cannot log in in the usual way.
What shall I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and after a reboot the issue went away.

One thing I would recommend is not to use the automatic login on Ubuntu 20.04 because that is what caused me to get into an infinite login loop since the machine thinks I am already logged in even though I am not.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using random guides from across the internet. It seems that the inttf guide installs both a patched kernel and a patched driver. Try installing the linux-generic package and removing the other linux images, and then try installing the package via apt. Nvidia purposefully removed support for legacy-340 drivers in kernels newer than 5.4 so you'll need to use the linux-generic image to circumvent that.

Comment: thanks, would it be possible for you to have a look on this question of mine as well https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04/1365644?noredirect=1#comment2345384_1365644 (it's with updated information / rephrased into a more coherent way, for this particular problem) ? thank you! (unfortunately the answers of the community for that question in the link above did not work for me)